# ZFS does not recognize new drive after resilvering

Tags: zfs

I tested my ZFS resilvering on my new NAS which has a 3-drive mirror zpool. So I attached another 4TB drive to the server in an external USB SATA dock and ran `zfs replace /dev/disk/by-id/ata-<ID_OF_ONE_INTERNAL_DISK_FROM_MIRROR> /dev/disk/by-id/ata-<ID_OF_DISK_IN_USB_DOCK>`. Then I let the resilvering fully complete, shut down the server and swapped the replaced hard drive in the server with the one that was in the USB dock before (so it was then in the server directly on the SATA port where the old drive was).

However, ZFS shows the drive as "UNAVAIL" (already showing the ID of the new drive - so it doesn't seem like it looks for the replaced HDD). Shouldn't it be able to recognize that the drive is the same device by the ID?

Edit:
Output requested by Daniel B:

```
The output differs a lot. ls -1 /dev/disk/by-id/ is missing 4 entries when drive is in USB dock (<disk-id>-part1, <disk-id>-part9, wwn-<HEXID>-part1, wwn-<HEXID>-part9). Both times, the disk ID alone and the HEXID alone (without the -part<n> suffixes appear in the output).

The fdisk -l also differs a lot.

Disk in server:
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size: 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size: 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel: gpt

In USB:

Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size: 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size: 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel: dos
```

Disk identifier is all zeros in the USB dock. Maybe that`s the problem? Are there USB controllers that don`t have this problem?

Comment: It’s not the “same device” though? Previously, it was in an USB dock. Now it’s not. USB enclosures usually fudge with identity data. Additionally, the dock may have emulated 4Kn sectors. Please provide the output of `ls -1 /dev/disk/by-id/` and `fdisk -l /dev/thedrive` when it is interally connected and when it is connected to the USB dock.

Comment: Added the output to the original question because it was so long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your USB drive dock is emulating native 4K sectors. This is visible from the `fdisk` output snippet you provided:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size: 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size: 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Various data structures (in MBR/GPT, ZFS, …) are pointing at sector numbers. These no longer match when the sectors size changes, even though all data is still there. For example, if something was pointing at sector 5 (starting from 1) before, that translated to 4096 bytes starting from offset (5 - 1) * 4096 bytes = 16384 bytes. Now, it’s pointing at 512 bytes starting from offset 4 * 512 bytes = 2048 bytes instead.

You should do away with your USB drive dock.

You will also have to re-add the drive while it is internally installed. You should do this as soon as possible to have the regular level of redundancy.

---

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to spot USB drive adapters/enclosures that have this “defect”. I’d hope that “brand” products don’t have this problem. But in the end, the only way to be sure is to check it manually.